# Set the value of jplist-drop-down after reloading

Tags: javascript, php, sorting, dropdown, jplist

I have a jplist dropdown list to change the sort field. When changed I am adding the value to php session. 
When reloading the page, I would like the value of that field to be the option selected on the sort dropdown list, but cannot find information on how to do it.
Have tried adding class active, selected, set default=true to the field and the remaining to false. All to no avail.
Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out about deepLinking after reading the docs. It´s exactly what I needed.